# Create a window with Lua?

Tags: lua, window

So as the title says I need to make code to create a window and add some content to it, like text, images etc, so Is it possible or not?
*(note that window needs to be interactive, that means you can code buttons, progress bars, selection boxes etc.)*

Comment: questions like this are best answered by referring to the reference manual or a simple websearch.

Comment: I recommend [this](https://glu1.sourceforge.io/) for writing 2D-games or other GUI applications in Lua, it runs on Win, Mac, Linux.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this in Lua alone. There are plenty of libraries and frameworks available that allow you to create graphical user interfaces.

http://lua-users.org/wiki/GraphicalUserInterfaceToolkits